# Problemas al intentar insertar datos desde un excel me dice que la tabla no existe

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, excel

El problema que tengo es ala hora de insertar los datos que selecciono mi excel no se si es problema que el nombre de mi tabla lleva un punto {edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact}

por que ala hora de realizar el insert con el controlador me tira el siguiente error

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table 'edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact' doesn't exist
>   (SQL: insert into `edavid`.`fcm_enl_ter_fact` (`PROVEEDOR`,
>   `DESC_ENLACE`, `NO_FACTURA`, `ID_ENLACE`, `VALOR_PAGO`, `PERIODO`,
>   `FECHA_FACTURA`, `FECHA_INGRESO`, `MONEDA`, `TC_FACTURA`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (PROVEEDOR, DESC_ENLACE,
>   NO_FACTURA, ID_ENLACE, VALOR_PAGO, PERIODO, FECHA_FACTURA,
>   FECHA_INGRESO, MONEDA, TC_FACTURA,

```
<form action="{{route('cargar_datos_usuarios')}}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        @csrf
                        @if(Session::has('message'))

                            <p>{{Session::get('message')}}</p>
                            @endif
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="archivo"/>.

                        <br>
                        <br><br>
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">ENVIAR</button>

   </form>
```

aqui esta mi ruta

```
Route::post('cargar_datos_usuarios',[
    'as'=>'cargar_datos_usuarios',
    'uses'=>'importarexcel@cargar_datos_usuarios'
]);
```

este es mi controlador

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Imports\Usersimport;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
//use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use App\importar;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class importarexcel extends Controller
{

    public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {


        $file=$request->file('file');
        Excel::Import(new Usersimport,$file);

        return back()->with('message','Importacion de usuarios completado');
}
}
```

En esta parte hago referencia a mi excel y controlador

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\importar;
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;

class Usersimport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new importar([
            'PROVEEDOR' => $row[0],
            'DESC_ENLACE' => $row[1],
            'NO_FACTURA' => $row[2],
            'ID_ENLACE' => $row[3],
            'VALOR_PAGO' => $row[4],
            'PERIODO' => $row[5],
            'FECHA_FACTURA' => $row[6],
            'FECHA_INGRESO' => $row[7],
            'MONEDA' => $row[8],
            'TC_FACTURA' => $row[9],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Este es mi modelo en el cual hago referencia ala tabla que tengo en mi base de datos

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class importar extends Model
{
    protected $table="edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact";
//
    protected  $fillable  = [
        'PROVEEDOR','DESC_ENLACE','NO_FACTURA','ID_ENLACE','VALOR_PAGO','PERIODO','FECHA_FACTURA','FECHA_INGRESO','MONEDA','TC_FACTURA'
    ];

}
```

Comment: Posiblemente debas entregar el nombre de la tabla entre comillas (como un literal) porque así nada más debe estar buscando un esquema edavid que contenga la tabla... por cierto, en qué BD trabajas?

Comment: Estoy con sql en xampp por que estoy haciendo pruebas antes

Comment: como asi entregar el nombre entre comillas podrias darme un ejemplo

Comment: lo intente de esta forma y nada lo mismo no encuentra la tabla     protected $table='edavid'.'fcm_enl_ter_fact';   me tira que sale asi la base `edavidfcm_enl_ter_fact`

Comment: sql? Querrás decir MySQL? Pues, es el que viene normalmente en XAMPP

Comment: si ese disculpa al parecer si es ese el problema el de el punto pero no se como podria hacer en este caso

Answer (score 0):

La solución siempre será usar sólo caracteres ASCII en los nombres de tablas y separar palabras con guiones bajos u otros caracteres que no compliquen tanto las cosas.

Ya que quieres usar el punto en el nombre de la tabla, es necesario usar backticks

```
CREATE TABLE `do.not.do.this` (col INT);
```

Que en tu caso, no sé si funcione con el Model de Laravel (pero vale la pena intentar, no conozco Laravel)

```
protected $table="`edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact`";
```

Fuente: [SO original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/776135/236345)

Comment: Bueno intente y me sigue dando el mismo error y al parecer si ese es el problema el punto por que cree otra tabla pero con guion bajo y si me funciono asi pero tengo otro problema ala hora de insertar me tira este error Undefined offset: 1